# VBA Vlookup returns N/A when opening file, but correct values if it's already open

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook doing a Vlookup in another workbook and I have it opening the file and then running a Vlookup. For some reason if it opens the file first, it only returns #N/A, but if the file is already open, it finds the values just fine. Is it something in the code?

```
Private Sub BarcodeVlookup(beginningNum As Integer, endingNum As Integer)
    Dim pvsReport As Excel.Workbook
    Dim tracker As Excel.Workbook
    Dim lookFor As Range
    Dim brandRng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim j As String

    If Not IsFileOpen("\\msfs05\Data1\SHARE\MDCM_Reports\LowesCom\PVS\PVS_Report.xlsx") Then
        Workbooks.Open ("\\msfs05\Data1\SHARE\MDCM_Reports\LowesCom\PVS\PVS_Report.xlsx")
        'Cut Barcode Column and Insert it at beginning of sheet
        Columns("J").Cut
        Columns("A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Set pvsReport = Workbooks("PVS_Report.xlsx")
        Set tracker = ThisWorkbook
    Else
        Set pvsReport = Workbooks("PVS_Report.xlsx")
        Set tracker = ThisWorkbook


    End If



    k = beginningNum


    Do Until k = endingNum + 1



        tracker.Sheets(1).Cells(k, "D").Value = Application.VLookup(Cells(k, "B"), pvsReport.Sheets(1).Range("A:M"), 13, False)


        tracker.Sheets(1).Cells(k, "A").Value = Application.VLookup(Cells(k, "B"), pvsReport.Sheets(1).Range("A:H"), 8, False)


        tracker.Sheets(1).Cells(k, "C").Value = Application.VLookup(Cells(k, "B"), pvsReport.Sheets(1).Range("A:B"), 2, False)

        If IsEmpty(Cells(k, "C").Value) Then
            tracker.Sheets(1).Cells(k, "C").Value = Application.VLookup(Cells(k, "B"), pvsReport.Sheets(1).Range("A:C"), 3, False)
        End If

        tracker.Sheets(1).Cells(k, "E").Value = Application.VLookup(Cells(k, "B"), pvsReport.Sheets(1).Range("A:R"), 18, False)

        tracker.Sheets(1).Cells(k, "F").Value = Application.VLookup(Cells(k, "B"), pvsReport.Sheets(1).Range("A:P"), 16, False)

        k = k + 1
    Loop

    MsgBox "Done! c[_] "
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check if the first argument of `Application.VLookup` is referencing the correct sheet, since you didn't use either tracker or pvsReport before `Cells(k, "B")`.

The active sheet probably changes when you open the workbook, so `Cells(k, "B")` will get data from `pvsReport` instead of `tracker`.

If `pvsreport` is already open, then the active sheet won't change.

Try changing:

```
Application.VLookup(Cells(k, "B"), ...
```

to:

```
Application.VLookup(tracker.Sheets(1).Cells(k, "B"), ...
```

Comment: That was it. I'm still new to this so I didn't realize it was switching to the active sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I changed tracker to point to `ThisworkBook.WorkSheets(1)`.  `Application.Vlookup` may work but you should use `WorkSheetFunction.Vlookup`.  I fully qualified your reference to Cells(k, "B").  You are inseting column J to the left of Column A.  Is that on `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)`  You should fully qualify that reference also. Using a With statement when dealing with such long references makes debugging easier.

```
Private Sub BarcodeVlookup(beginningNum As Integer, endingNum As Integer)
    Dim pvsReport As Excel.Workbook
    Dim tracker As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lookFor As Range
    Dim brandRng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim j As String
    Set tracker = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    If Not IsFileOpen("\\msfs05\Data1\SHARE\MDCM_Reports\LowesCom\PVS\PVS_Report.xlsx") Then
        Workbooks.Open ("\\msfs05\Data1\SHARE\MDCM_Reports\LowesCom\PVS\PVS_Report.xlsx")
        'Cut Barcode Column and Insert it at beginning of sheet
        Columns("J").Cut
        Columns("A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    End If

    Set pvsReport = Workbooks("PVS_Report.xlsx")



    k = beginningNum

    With pvsReport.Worksheets(1)

        Do Until k = endingNum + 1

            tracker.Cells(k, "D").Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(tracker.Cells(k, "B"), .Range("A:M"), 13, False)
            tracker.Cells(k, "A").Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(tracker.Cells(k, "B"), .Range("A:H"), 8, False)
            tracker.Cells(k, "C").Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(tracker.Cells(k, "B"), .Range("A:B"), 2, False)

            If IsEmpty(Cells(k, "C").Value) Then
                tracker.Cells(k, "C").Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(tracker.Cells(k, "B"), .Range("A:C"), 3, False)
            End If

            tracker.Cells(k, "E").Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(tracker.Cells(k, "B"), .Range("A:R"), 18, False)
            tracker.Cells(k, "F").Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(tracker.Cells(k, "B"), .Range("A:P"), 16, False)

            k = k + 1
        Loop

    End With

    MsgBox "Done! c[_] "
    Unload Me
End Sub
```